# What is this "dice, cubes, hexes and ships" game?

Tags: identify-this-game

I've seen it in a "Game mechanics" presentation. What is the name of this game showcased in the photo below?

[image: Image from presentation]

Answer (score 15):

Found it. It's called [Eclipse](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/72125/eclipse).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good sleuthing work! Thanks for including a comparative image.

Comment: Confirmed (played it)